# Django parameterized tests - Problems

Tags: python, django, testing

I want to test my Django app. To avoid code clones, i want to usere paramerezided testes. I also want to use variables i initialized in the setUp(), to avoid hardcoding e.g. primary keys.

But i did not find a fitting solution.

Idea 1: Loop

```
from django.test import TestCase
from app.models import Example

class TestClass(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUp(self):
        self.param1 = Example.object.create(att="foo")
        self.param2 = Example.object.create(att="bar")

    def test_example(self):
        
        
        for testcase in testcases:
            
            self.assertEqual(param.att,expected)
```

Problem: Cant find failed tests without adding extra debug messages.

Idea 2: parameterized library

```
from django.test import TestCase
from app.models import Example

from parameterized import parameterized

class TestClass(TestCase):
    param1 = None
    param2 = None
    def setUp(self):
        self.param1 = Example.object.create(att="foo")
        self.param2 = Example.object.create(att="bar")

    @parameterized.expand([
        (param1,"foo"),
        (param2,"bar"),
    ])
    def test_example(self,param, expected):
        self.assertEqual(param.att,expected)
```

Problem: param is still None in the test

Idea 3: getattr

```
from django.test import TestCase
from app.models import Example

from parameterized import parameterized

class TestClass(TestCase):
    param1 = None
    param2 = None
    def setUp(self):
        self.param1 = Example.object.create(att="foo")
        self.param2 = Example.object.create(att="bar")

    @parameterized.expand([
        ("param1","foo"),
        ("param2","bar"),
    ])
    def test_example(self,param, expected):
        param = getattr(self, param)
        expected = getattr(self, expected)
        self.assertEqual(param.att,expected)
```

Problem: very slow

Comment: What is the `"` in `expected?

Comment: As for the "very slow", what do you mean with slow? the mechanics of running a test are quite slow, especially if *database queries* are involved: it will each time create both objects in the database, and remove these.

Comment: The " is a typo, sorry